# Give permission for a user to edit a course

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.1+. I have created different user roles, a 'course creator' role who can create and edit courses. By mistake, I added some courses after logging in as super administrator. So now those courses cannot be edited by the 'course creator'. Is there a way to give permission for a particular user to edit a specific course?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new capabilities to your role as follows:

1. Login as admin
2. Go to: Dashboard / ► Site administration / ► Users / ► Permissions / ► Define roles
3. In the list of roles, identify your role (course creator) and click on the icon "Edit" (the gear icon)
4. You should be now in the "Editing role 'course creator' Tab. Scroll down and look for the "Capability" section (which is very long).
5. look for the capability `moodle/course:update` and click its "Allow" checkbox.
6. Look for and allow any other capability you want to give to your role.
7. Save and try to edit the courses with users having the "course creator" role.

Comment: I have set default course settings to hide the course on creation. Later admin will approve and show the course. Giving moodle/course:update permission will enable them to edit the course show/hide option.

Comment: Then you should give (only) more granular capabilities to the course creator, like Hide/show activities and / or moodle/course:changefullname, and so on, tailoring exactly what you want them to do.

Comment: Scroll the list of capabilities and choose what you want them to do.